# PHP include content and move to an id anchor fails to load

Tags: php

I am trying to load some content with php, and some of the navigation links refer to an anchor tag.

when the page loads there is a nav list, and I can click on any of the items which will scroll the page to the correct anchor.  If I click the last item (forum) it loads different content, and I can never go back to the original content.

If I change one of the links to be just href="index.php?content=main then that link will reload the main content.  So for some reason the anchor tag # is causing this to fail, if I change the last link to be href="index.php?content=forum#test" then the forum content will not load either.

Is there some fundamental mistake I am making or can this not be done in this way?

I can right click on the link and open in a new tab and they work fine and scroll to the correct anchor.  A left click just seems to do nothing, not even a change in the address bar.

Here is the code.

```html
<!-- navigation menu -->
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li><a href="index.php?content=main#action" class="active">Living The Dream</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?content=main#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?content=main#reality">The Reality</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?content=main#setup">Downloads & Setup</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?content=forum">Forum</a></li>
    </ul> 
    <!-- end of navigation menu -->
      
  </div> 
<!-- end of the sidebar -->
    
<!-- content container -->
  <div id="container"> 
    <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['content']))
            {
            $parts = explode('#', $_GET['content']);
            print_r($parts);
            $content = $parts[0];
            $content .= '.php';
            }
        else
            {
            $content="main.php";
            }
        $allowed = Array();

        $dh = opendir(".");
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh)))
            {
                if (!is_dir("./$file"))
                    {
                        $expl = explode('.',$file);
                        if ($expl[1] == "php")
                            {
                                $allowed[] = $file;
                            }
                    }
            }

        closedir($dh);

        print($content);

        if (in_array($content, $allowed))
            {
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$content);
            }
            else
            {
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."main.php");
            }
      ?>
```

Comment: Apparently, hashtags don't work in PHP. So I've read quite a few times.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats because that part of the URL is never sent to the server. It's only used client side

Comment: @Fred-ii- they work as normal but seems to be preventing my php from including the file.  Probably as DarkBee says it is not sending the request but trying to handle it inside the browser.  Is there way to do both?

Comment: I couldn't say Rob, wish I could though. I never use hashtags in PHP. A client-side method may be better.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `#` in your querystring? Just encode it. `index.php?content=main%23action`

Fragments aren't sent in HTTP Request. The reason is that the fragment identifier is only used by the browser.

Comment: No, the # represents and anchor in html that would open that page at the contact section.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3 will explain it better than I do.

Comment: Actually I just re-thought what you said and tried it.  The content will now load, but it is not jumping to the id anchor.

Comment: thats just the same problem.  If I include the anchor # in the link then the php does not run.  If I use the %23 option the php is run, but the anchor is ignored and it loads the content at the top of the page.

Comment: I'll rewrite it, `index.php?content=main%23action#idanchor`

Comment: yes, and it is still the same problem,  You can write it any way you want.  href="index.php?content=main%23this_will_not#work_because_it_has_the_hash_in_then_link"  The browser does not attempt to reload the page because of the # so the page never changes.  So the main content or the forum content or what ever content is never loaded.

Comment: If you're in the `index.php?content=main%23action#anchor` page, and you click `index.php?content=main%23action#anotheranchor`, definitely the page doesn't reload since the resource is the same. This is how the browser works. Seems easy for me. My test: http://pastebin.com/2r1wVbcq . Can you give some more detail of the problem? Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: The problem is when you are in "index.php?content=forum" and click the link index.php?content=main%23action#anchor the page stays on the forum page and can not load the main page content because of the # in the link to the main page.  Yes, same results in chrome and firefox.  My solution is to use PHP to write the links based on the current content.

Answer (score 0):

DarkBee had the answer, any link with a # in it does not get passed to the server but is handled by the browser.  It looks like I will need re-write the links based on the content.

This is how I am currently doing it.  I don't know much about PHP so of any one has a better way let me know.

At the end on my index.php I have this code:

```html
<?php 
    # Used as part of the navigation solution
    # see nav.php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "element_to_scroll_to = document.getElementById('".$_GET['a']."');";
    echo "element_to_scroll_to.scrollIntoView();";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

and in my nav.php I have this.

```html
<ul id="navigation">
<?php
    # Take an array of contents and links.
    # Depending on current content page write the links
    $nc = explode('.',$content);

    $navs[0] = array("main", "action", "Living The Dream");
    $navs[1] = array("main", "about", "About");
    $navs[2] = array("main", "reality", "The Reality");
    $navs[3] = array("main", "setup", "Downloads & Setup");
    $navs[4] = array("forum", "", "Forum");

    foreach ($navs as $link) {
        if ($link[0] == $nc[0]) {
            echo('<li><a href="#'.$link[1].'">'.$link[2].'</a></li>');     
        } else {
            echo('<li><a href="index.php?content='.$link[0].'&a='.$link[1].'">'.$link[2].'</a></li>');
        }
    }
?>
  

</ul>
```